# Not getting calculated value with SUM() in pig

Tags: hadoop, sum, apache-pig

My commands are as under:

```
Z = LOAD '/..file_path' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:CHARARRAY,gpa:int,salary:int);
y = GROUP Z BY gpa;
R = FOREACH y GENERATE SUM(Z.salary);
```

I am getting the output of

```
DUMP R;
```

as :

```
{all,()};
```

Please guide me. 
TIA.

Comment: can u provide input and output sample

Comment: krishna 65 7889
bhavik 56   4325
nihrka 89  5668 -- input.

And output: ()

Comment: for each gpa ur calculating total salary...script is correct then

Comment: how are you executing the commands?

Comment: How as in ? im executing the commands as written from grunt shell.

Comment: Your data is separated by space or comma? Most likely your load statement is incorrect.

Comment: @inquisitive_mind Even if i add the load statment with PigStatement(','), and records with ',' seperated, it gives me result as the record of all salaries.

Comment: "Gives me result as the record of all Salaries".What is the expected result that you are looking for? Sum(Z.salary) will give the total of all salaries.

Comment: @inquisitive_mind I meant it is giving me the whole salary column as it is and not the total of the salaries. :(   Should this work ? If it should, the n there might be some issue with my pig. As I am facing similar issue for MAX() as well, as described in my previous question today.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GROUP ALL instead of GROUP BY to get the [SUM](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#SUM).

```
Z = LOAD '/..file_path' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:CHARARRAY,gpa:int,salary:int);
y = GROUP Z ALL;
R = FOREACH y GENERATE SUM(Z.salary);
DUMP R;
```

Comment: @KrishnaShah Please mark it as answer so that question is closed?